# Can't Decide value of ERRORLEVEL

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pipe

I have a batch script that loops on the output of an ant call and checks if a string exists in the output, if the string exists we move on to the next step, else we terminate the execution..

Here's a pseudo snippet from my script:

```
FOR %%A in ('cmd here') do (
echo %%A | find /i "string">nul
if errorlevel 1 echo sth
echo %errorlevel%
)
```

Now all the lines in the output seem to go into this if and echo the line, even replacing  1 with 0 doesn't change anything at all, the behavior stays the same.

Furthermore the %errorlevel% is always set to 0, which I believe I understand. As errorlevel is available it doesn't backfall to %errorlevel%, am I right here?

I know that the error level should return the result of the pipe, such as in the tee cmd, where it goes

```
dir | tee foo.txt
```

Am I missing sth here? How should I achieve this thing?

Comment: Since you are reading `ErrorLevel` within a parenthesised block of code you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (`!ErrorLevel!`); otherwise, `%ErrorLevel%` expands to the value present *before* the entire block is executed...

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are after. If find (not the pipe) does return an error it had found nothing. If you want to react on a find you should use `if not errorlevel 1 ...` Or you could use conditional execution with `echo %%A | find /i "string">nul && Echo found || Echo not found`

Comment: I see.. thanks for the link and the help.. working now